# Xen to KVM windows guest migration

Tags: xen, migration, kvm-virtualization

I'm trying to work out how to migrate a Xen based windows server guest to a KVM host.

I've grabbed a copy of the Xen image and run an image conversion on it.

`kvm-img convert -O raw 8345617d-0654-4cac-b92f-e29f6b0e1005.vhd win2K3.raw`

Unfortunately when I try and run kvm with this raw image, it can't find a bootable device.

Has anyone managed this translation?  I'm guessing its a bit simplistic given that I can't find much on the great search engine in the cloud to suggest this as an option.

Ta
Peter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is virt-v2v, here's a good explanation: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Xen_to_KVM_migration

Comment: Thanks for this dyasny.  My issue is that I need to try this migration on a machine that doesn't have any of the Xen stuff on it (does have kvm and libvirt though) as I'm not game to play with the old production server to try and migrate this image (very very fragile).  

I have grabbed the vhd file from the machine however but can't seem to find a sane way to work with this file.  Should virt-v2v work on a Ubuntu system with just the vhd file?

Comment: it can remotely connect to the Xen server, and copy the VM to the libvirt server. On the other hand, vhd is a format suported by `qemu-img`, so you might be able to convert it to raw or qcow2 and then just attach the image to a KVM VM.

Comment: also, you might want to check the guest OS for where it boots from. Xen disks look like /dev/xvdX while KVM disks are either /dev/hdX (ide) or /dev/vdX (virtIO)